Evaluating the coprimality in a bivariate polynomial equation
Given a prime $p>2$, let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that $x>y>0$ and
$$ \begin{equation} x^p-y^p=(x-y)^p+pxy(x-y)R \tag{1} \label{eq:one} \end{equation} $$
where $R$ is a bivariate polynomial $R(x,y)$; it is routine to verify that $R=1$ if $p=3$.
Let us rearrange Eq. \eqref{eq:one} conveniently as
$$ \begin{equation} R(x,y) = \frac{x^p-y^p-(x-y)^p}{pxy(x-y)} .\tag{2} \label{eq:two} \end{equation} $$
Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive integers such that $c>b>a$; the triple is subject to the triangular inequalities $c<b+a$, $c-b<a$, and $c-a<b$.
We are interested in the case of $R(c,b)$ and $R(c,a)$ relatively prime; in particular, we ask:

Does the coprimality between $R(c,a)$ and $R(c,b)$ imply that
$a$, $b$, $c$ are pairwise coprime? Please confirm it is wrong for any odd prime $p>3$.
Does the pairwise coprimality of $a$, $b$, $c$ imply that $R(c,a)$ and $R(c,b)$ are relatively prime? Please confirm it is always true (except the case $a+b=c$, excluded by the triangular inequality).
Is there any historical record, likely from 17th century scholars, about the coprimality conditions in Eq. \eqref{eq:two}?


Of course, for $p=3$, the answer for 1. is trivially no, and yes for 2. I think you should add more context, like why the question is interesting, and what partial results you have.

Thank you @PeterMueller. We are accomplishing a project about Pascal's triangle properties and detailed history (beyond Pascal's own work). The above questions are very specific, as the one we posed some months ago about the exact origin of another binomial property.

Our past curiosity was satisfied here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463734/about-the-exact-origin-of-a-binomial-congruence

Now, we would like to verify whether statement 1 is always (with any odd prime p) wrong and statement 2 is always true. In addition, if possible, we wish to track the first historical discussion about such properties (scholars, books, letters...).

If $a+b=c$ then $R(c,a)=R(c,b)$ so statement 2 is not always true.

Thank you @vuur for your precious help! Is it the only exception? What if we had the additional condition R(c,a) different from R(c,b)?

Actually, dear @vuur, a,b,c are sides of a triangle so that c<a+b. Thanks to your precious help we will opportunely edit the question.

$7$ divides both $R(13, 11)$ and $R(13, 4)$ for $p=5$ and $13<11+4$. There are lots of other solutions you can find with a computer. So statement 2 is not always true. (Also the three new inequalities are all the same).

Thank you dear @vuur! Do you think it is so trivial that no ancient scholar deepened the topic? Or do you have some clues about such a discussion in the past (at least before computer era)?

Re, this seems like a separate question, and, since it is explicitly more about the history of mathematics than about the mathematics itself, probably more appropriate for HSMSE.

Thank you @LSpice.
